Justification of the trigonometric substitution used to compute the derivative of $y = \arctan(\frac{2x}{1-x^2})$.
When $y=\arctan(\frac{2x}{1-x^2})$ to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ we may substitute $x=\tan (u)$, then we have $y=\arctan(\tan 2u)$, at this point the book I'm reading (Differential Calculus by Joseph Edwards) concludes $y=2u$ and $dy/dx = \frac{2}{1+x^2}$, now my question is how can we say that $y=2u$? $\arctan(\tan(x))=x$ only when $x$ is in $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, how do we know that $2u$ lies in that interval?
I have seen this sort of a thing done all over the internet (with integrals and other derivatives) but it's never justified.
I know that chain rule may be applied but I want the justification for this way of doing it as trigonometric substitutions come up everywhere.

Hint: differentiate $\tan y=\tan 2u$, then rearrange using its consequence $\sec^2y=\sec^22u$ obtained by $t\mapsto1+t^2$.

@J.G. Differentiate with respect to what?

Preferably $x$, but $u$ would work.

It Works. Thanks!

$y = \arctan(\tan(2u)) = 2u$ holds only when $2u$ is adjusted to lie within the principal branch $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, which ensures that the identity holds. The justification is therefore inherent in $\arctan$, which gives the principal value when it takes $\tan(x)$ as it's argument.

Edit:
To address your point in the comments: when we write $y = \arctan(\tan(y))$, we aren't directly equating $y = 2u$ (the argument of $\tan$, here $2u$ for the example) in all cases. Instead, we are ensuring that the output lies within the principal range of $ \arctan $, $ \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. For instance, if $ u = \frac{\pi}{3} $, then $2u = \frac{2\pi}{3} $. Note $\tan(2u) = \tan\left( \frac{2\pi}{3} \right)$, but however $ \arctan\left( \tan\left( \frac{2\pi}{3} \right) \right)$ will return the equivalent angle within the principal branch. The correct value returned is
$$ \arctan(\tan(2u)) = -\frac{\pi}{3}$$, since $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ lies outside the principal branch, and the tangent function has a period of $\pi$, so the angle is adjusted inherent to $\arctan$ to fall within $ \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ Hope that cleasr things up.

Okay so we know that $y = \arctan(\tan(2u))$ does not always mean that $y = 2u$, since $\arctan(x)$ function maps input to $\left( -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$. For this reason we can't continue a proof using $x = \arctan(\tan(x))$.
When $2u$ lies outside this range, the result of $\arctan(\tan(2u))$ is adjusted to the equivalent angle within the principal branch, as outlined above, by adding or subtracting multiples of $\pi$.
So, if $2u > \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\arctan(\tan(2u)) = 2u - \pi$.
Similarly, if $2u < -\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\arctan(\tan(2u)) = 2u + \pi$.
Therefore while $y = 2u$ holds in the case where $2u \in \left( -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$, the value of $y$ is adjusted outside this range to ensure it lies within $\left( -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$.

Isn't u adjusted to lie in that interval? And not 2u? For example if x = √3, u = π/3 thus 2u is 2π/3 and arctan(tan (2π/3)) ≠ 2π/3.

You're right in noting that ( 2u ) is not directly guaranteed to lie within the principal branch of the arctangent. $ \arctan(\tan(2u)) $ adjusts $2u $ to the appropriate value in the interval $ \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, but this is an inherent feature of the $\arctan$ function, which outputs the principal value for any argument, effectively wrapping values that exceed the range of $ \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) $

As I see it, the fact that arctan(tan(2u)) = 2u is absolutely essential for the proof.

See edit, to clarify. Hope that it makes more sense

@Zaid note that $\arctan (\tan(x))$ is not always equal to  $x$

That's essentially my argument.      Can you continue the proof from $\arctan(tan(2u)=2u$?

@Zaid see final edit. Hope thats all clarified now

Oh I see, we can write $\arctan( \tan(2u))=2u+n\pi$ where $n$ is an integer, and then after differentiating $2u+n\pi$ we get the desired result as $n\pi$ is a constant.

This is sort of sneaky, and really does demand closer examination:

When $y=\arctan(\frac{2x}{1-x^2})$ to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ we may
substitute $x=\tan (u)$,

Why can we substitute $x = \tan u$? Answer: because for any number $x$, there's a number $u$ whose tangent is $x$. And we can, in fact, find such a number that lies between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. To put it differently, the restriction of $\tan$ to the interval $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$ is a bijection between that interval and $\mathbb R$. (Indeed, it's a differentiable bijection!) So from here on in, $u$ lies strictly between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. The author should have mentioned this, or indicated that without that domain restriction, the choice of $u$ is ambiguous...but then things get messy, and you have to keep talking about the ambiguity, etc.

then we have $y=\arctan(\tan 2u)$,

This is because for any number $q$, we have  $\tan(2q) = \frac{2 \tan q}{1 + \tan^2 q}$, which is proved with a few double-angle formulas and some algebra. Applying this to $q = u$ gives us the necessary equality. I'm guessing you understood this already.

at this point the book I'm reading (Differential Calculus by Joseph
Edwards) concludes $y=2u$ and $dy/dx = \frac{2}{1+x^2}$,

Right -- the book is saying that $\arctan(\tan(2u)) = 2u$. That is, as you observe, only true when $\tan(2u)$ lies in the right interval. Read on...

now my question is how can we say that $y=2u$?

And that's an excellent question, showing careful reading of the sort that I'd never have done when I was learning calculus!
What seems suspicious at this point is that $u$ can be chosen between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, and for a number $a$ in that range, we certainly have $\arctan(tan(a)) = a$. But the number $2u$ may well not be in that range. So what happens then?
Let's check with an explicit example.
Let's pick $x = \tan(\frac{3\pi}{8}) \approx 2.414$. (More precisely, it's $2 \sqrt{2}$.  In this case, $u = \frac{3\pi}{8} \approx 1.178$, which I chose because $2u$ will be outside the chosen interval.
We get that $\frac{2x}{1-x^2} = -1$, and so $y = \arctan(2x/(1-x^2)) = \arctan(-1) = -\pi/4 \approx -0.7854$. This is, of course, nowhere near $2u$, which is approximately $2.36$.
So the claim made by the author is actually false.
This leads one to the question "Well in that case, how did it arrive at the correct result?", and that's a whole other story (and periodicity as mentioned in @MxJ's answer comes into it).
But the short summary is this: the claims made are false; the conclusions derived are true.
As a textbook author myself, I can't really hold this against the author all that strongly. We try to double-check things, and sometimes we mess up, just like our students.

That was helpful thanks!
